# Associate Meta Data or Source File failed to save

Tags: eclipse

I am having problem in saving the code using Eclipse to Salesforce.
Previously it was working fine and suddenly I can't save any file.

I keep having `"Associate meta Data or source file failed to save"` warning.
And there is no error in my code.
I even try to just type enter one line and saved , but still hit same error.

Anyone face this kind of error before?

Comment: If you use Window -> Show View -> Error Log and then double click you will get more detail on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the cross sign on my project. When I check the classes and other, seem all ok.

So I refresh whole project again from Server, seem like working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before and you should just be hitting the Save button, or CTRL+S to save content to the server.  you can also use the Save to Server option in the Force.com context submenu, but anything else is probably not something they put in native support for.